# Starting an Android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, development-environment

I have recently started to enjoy Android development and I have some projects that I want to develop.

I usually develop with IntelliJ and my recent sdk target was 21. I noticed there are several things that I have missed such as Maven, Gradle, maybe using a lower sdk target and Asynctasks.

So my question is how to I start with a good Android project? How do I use Graddle or Maven? and what sdk target should be the minimum in 2015 according to you guys?

Basically what should I do or think about when I'm developing in Android?

Comment: I suggest use Android studio, and minimum SDK level is 14. If you use Android studio it will use the build system called Gradle.

Comment: What are the benefits of Gradle? Can I use other plugins such as https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are not compel to use Gradle as newbie because it's the build system of android studio ,and it will generated automatically. so you have no work to do with it directly as a beginner.

and for what min sdk , for now u can set it as ICS4.0 (API 14) because in this case your app will targeting more than ~ 87% of users.

-my opinion is to leave this side things, and focus on main programing stuff, and good luck.